# Power BI - Refreshing and DataSource.Error

Tags: date, powerbi, dataflow, powerbi-datasource

I have some issue on refreshing data flow on Power BI, Normally the each table taken 2 mins to complete, but the issue that I am facing is data flow keep continue refreshing. and showing failed with the reason : "Error: Encountered user gateway exception: '[DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode]=-2147467259 [DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult]=-2147467259 [Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Detail]:http://XXXX/XX"

Answer (score 0):

We found that the report connection could not connect to the SQL Analysis service, so we tried the following option.

Restart the SQL Analysis service.
Refresh the SQL Analysis database
Connect on SQL Management studio success
Then refresh the report link in Power BI Side
Check if the error is resolved